# Is there any memory leak in the function like function(new Foo())?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am writing a hierarchical state machine recently. I want to set an initial sub-state when transit to another super-state.

Thus I have the codes as follows to set the initial state. The first version

```
void Foo::setInitialSubState(State* next_state){
  if(state_)
    delete state_;

  state_ = next_state;
  state_->enter(*this);
}
```

Then I found out that if(state_) always return true.. So I removed it. This function is called in constructor Foo::Foo().

```
Foo::Foo()
{
  setInitialSubState(new State());
}
```

There is a segment fault error when I want to delete the state_. So I initialize the member var state_ in constructor.

```
Foo::Foo()
{
  state_ = 0;
  setInitialSubState(new State());
}
```

This will solve the segment fault problem.

I want to know if there is memory leak problem when I use setInitialSubState(new State())? I cannot figure out.. How can I change if(state_) to avoid delete() to cause segfault?

Thanks for all your kind advices..

----edit----

To make myself more clear about the memory leak part, I think I can rephrase the question as

```
 void Foo::setInitialSubState(State* next_state)
{
  state_ = next_state;
  delete state_;
}

Foo::Foo()
{
  state_ = 0;
  setInitialSubState(new State());
}
```

Is there any memory leak?

Comment: You can call delete on a pointer to 0. If you call it on a random address, it can cause a segfault. Always initialize your pointers.

Comment: To still answer the initial question, yes, calling `new Foo()` can cause a memory leak under certain conditions (mainly in case of exceptions).

Comment: Just remove the if(state_) part and keep the delete state_ part.

Comment: @Jaciq This can cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Leandros I don't believe deleting a null pointer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Jaciq `delete` does a `null` check, anyway, forget my comment, I was thinking about an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @Blacktempel thanks I have read some where that delete a 0 pointer will always work so I tried to initialize state_.  How I can know that state_ actually point to something and can be deleted?

Comment: @Jaciq If I initialize state_ it works. But simply remove if(state_) part cause segfault

Comment: The pointer is either 0, or it points to a valid value. It's your responsibility to take care of that.

Comment: @tianb03 I meant keep your current code with the initialisation, pointers should in general always be initialised, and remove the if statement.

Comment: why don't you take a look at std::unique_ptr?

Comment: Regarding your last edit: Did you really mean to `delete state_` AFTER assigning it?

Comment: @CyberSpock ok I will take a look at that.. Though I have written quite a lot of code but I am not a pro programmer and I even do not know std::unique_ptr...

Comment: @anderas Yes. I am not sure because I am not very clear about the pass by value pass by reference and pass pointer such kind of thing...

Comment: @tianb03 with your edit, you'll have even more leaks, since now both the memory allocated by state and next_state will be lost.
When you pass by pointer, the pointer still points to the exact same area of the memory it did outside of the function.

On a different note. Are you even sure you want to use pointers in this case?

Comment: @Jaciq When I assign next_state to state_, then I delete state_, I thought this is the only block of memory I have allocated..

Comment: @tianb03 Yes, I messed part of the comment up. See the answer by CyberSpock. Also, I really doubt using pointers is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below function is not doing anything, you are deleting the object passed to the function. If state_ is previously pointing to something then it will cause a memory leak.

```
void Foo::setInitialSubState(State* next_state)
{
  state_ = next_state;  // state_ points to the object that next_state points to.
  delete state_; // deletes what state_ and next_state points to.
}
```

an alternative is to declare state_ as a smart pointer, then you do not need to delete the pointer

```
std::unique_ptr<State> state_;

...

void Foo::setInitialSubState(State* next_state)
{
  state_ = std::make_unique<State>(next_state);
}
```

The below code is fine, although you may want to use `nullptr` instead 0 to make it more clear that `state_` is a pointer and also move it up to the initialization list:

```
Foo::Foo() : state_(nullptr)
{
  setInitialSubState(new State());
}
```

Comment: Did you really mean to use `make_shared` rather than `make_unique` there? If so, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @tianb03 Instead of letting your `setInitialSubState` taka a pointer, why not let it take the arguments needed to construct the `State` object. The calling code will then not show the use if `new` anymore which might avoid confusion about ownership. It's really a wrapper for `make_shared` anyway as it is: `template <typename ... Args> void Foo::setInitialSubState(Args&& ... args) { _state = make_shared(new State(std::forwards<Args>(args) ...)); }`

Comment: @JorenHeit fixed, thanks for the feedback seems I did a typo.

Comment: @JorenHeit Thanks for your advices. I am also thinking of how to re-organize the code. Most of the codes are referred to some game pattern programming blog, but it is quite difficult for me to manipulate the snippets.. I am more focused on sensors and motion control, will try to understand your comments firstly

Comment: @tianb03 just send me an email if you need more explaining (anders43@gmail.com) cheers

Answer (score 3):

Initially the uninitialized pointer of `state_` has some value that is why the `if(state_)` enters and tries to `delete` some random pointer.

Calling delete on zero pointer is safe that is why Your fix works.

About memory-leak: if there is no destructor for the Foo class then You could have one, but to be sure You should post more code..

Comment: Jaciq leave a comment: "with your edit, you'll have even more leaks, since now both the memory allocated by state and next_state will be lost. When you pass by pointer, the pointer still points to the exact same area of the memory it did outside of the function. " Is it true? I though my edit and the original are the same question...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using g++ then [valgrind is your friend](http://valgrind.org/).
There are similar tools for OSX, iOS, Windows, Android, Solaris ... .

Some commercial, some free. Ask around.

These are an essential in any C/C++ programmers toolbox and will show you there is a problem and where it is.